# How do I permit Windows 10 to ask what device has been connected after setting a default audio device?

Tags: windows-10, audio, default-settings

On this Windows 10 laptop, plugging speakers or headphones into the audio jack caused a prompt to appear requesting that the user specify what kind of device had just been connected. A checkbox permitted the user to designate the selected device as the default, so that the prompt would no longer appear whenever something was plugged in. How would I go about reinstating this prompt and undoing this default selection?

Answer (score 0):

If you select speaker as default output at the first time, unplug it and plugin headphone, will it prompt the option again?

You can change the default playback device in GUI settings, go ahead :
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/102323-change-default-audio-playback-device-windows-10-a.html

In addition, try to clear the audio device cache in registry 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render

Note:please backup the registry before you delete it.